# Immediate ES6 export doesn't seem to work

Tags: import, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm developing with Webpack (hot reloading) and I'm importing React components with `import Sample from './components/Sample/Sample'`, however, I'd like to simple be able to import with `import {Sample, SampleTwo} from './components'`.

The former works, however, the latter throws an error.

```
    components/
        index.jsx
        Sample/
            Sample.jsx
        SampleTwo/
            SampleTwo.jsx
```

Inside of index.jsx, I've tried:

`export {default as Sample} from './component/Sample/Sample'` which works, however, I get a warning from Webpack saying it's in read-only mode. Then, I tried the following:

```
    import Sample from './components/Sample/Sample';

    export default {
        Sample: Sample
    }
```

Comment: "however, the latter throws an error." --- and that error is.....?

Comment: Do you need a `default`?  Why not just `export` without a default, then all should work when importing.

Comment: This discussion might help https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/158

Answer (score 1):

As [Davin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781707/davin-tryon) suggested, you can just export the object whose properties reference your components:

```
import Sample from './components/Sample/Sample';

export { Sample: Sample }
```

or even better:

```
import Sample from './components/Sample/Sample';

export { Sample }
```

Then you can import this way:

```
import { Sample } from './components'
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, however, it doesn't seem to work at all within the app :(

Comment: It simply says that the module cannot be found. I revert back to the typical way and it works. So, I tried the other syntax as well, however, I get the Hot Reloading warning, as I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

components/Sample/Sample.jsx

```
[...]

class Sample extends React.Component
{
    [...]
}

export default Sample;
```

Component/SampleTwo/SampleTwo.jws

```
[...]

class SampleTwo export React.Component
{
    [...]
}

export default SampleTwo;
```

components/index.jsx

```
import Sample from './Sample/Sample'
import SampleTwo from './SampleTwo/SampleTwo'

export {Sample, SampleTwo};
```

Comment: What error did you see, and can you show your ``webpack.config.js``?